# read sockets in array using <$socket[i]> in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sockets

I want to read my sockets and do a "getline" on them.

```
my @socket1;
$socket1[0] = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    Type     => SOCK_STREAM,
    PeerAddr => "127.0.0.1",
    Proto    => "tcp",
    PeerPort => $dbase_param{camera_stream}
) or die "Cannot open socket on port " . $dbase_param{camera_stream} . ".\n";

print { $socket1[0] } "\n";
my $ligne = <$socket1[0]>;

while ( !( $ligne =~ /Content-Length:/ ) ) {
    $ligne = <$socket1[0]>;
}
```

It will tell me `Use of uninitialized value $ligne in pattern match (m//)` for the second `$ligne = <$socket1[0]>;`

I don't understand wy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angle brackets are used also for `glob()`,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e '$ligne = <$socket1[0]>;'
use File::Glob ();
$ligne = glob($socket1[0]);
```

so if you're not using plain scalar as socket, you might to be more explicit by using [`readline()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html),

```
$ligne = readline($socket1[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [I/O Operator `<EXPR>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) can mean either [`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) or [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) depending on `EXPR`.

In this instance, you need to use an explicit `readline` in order to accomplish what you want.

Additionally, you should always perform the reading of a handle in a `while` loop and put any additional flow logic inside the loop.  This is because a `while` loop that is reading from a file will automatically check for an `eof` condition.  The way that your code is currently written you could end up with an infinite loop if it never finds that regular expression.

To fix both issues, I would therefore rewrite your processing to the following:

```
my $ligne;

while ( $ligne = readline $socket1[0] ) {
    last if $ligne =~ /Content-Length:/;
}
```